# Why do some browsers seem to require a UTF-8 charset on JSON data for display?

Tags: json, browser, utf-8

So I see the A: [What is the correct JSON content type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/what-is-the-correct-json-content-type/477819#477819)  - `application/json` as well as [What content type header to use for JSON? "application/json; charset=utf-8 " or "application/json"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19814908/why-content-type-header-to-use-for-json-application-json-charset-utf-8-or) and [What does "Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8" really mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254891/what-does-content-type-application-json-charset-utf-8-really-mean/9254967#9254967)

As noted there, [RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159) says that the default encoding for JSON is utf-8 and notes that:

> No "charset" parameter is defined for this registration.
> Adding one really has no effect on compliant recipients.

However, in reality, some browsers at least (Safari and Firefox) seem to apply "auto-detect" to the JSON data unless a charset parameter is added (see [this ticket filed against me](http://unicode.org/cldr/trac/ticket/7520) and also the related SO question linked above). I haven't tested XMLHTTPRequest implementations so I can't say either way. I assume they handle `application/json` properly.

So I think my question is slightly different - for display *in the browser*, is the charset required because these browsers' built-in JSON display is not actually RFC compliant?

Answer (score 1):

There is a Firefox bug on this: "[Don't honor charset when viewing JSON](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=741776)" #741776 says that XHR ignores charset and that docview shold also.

Comment: It's 2017 and this is still a common bug across a different browsers, usually when viewing JSON responses in the browser. *sad face*