# non english characters encoding in node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, encoding

I have a PHP code and node js code that saves and get some info to/from MySQL database. Some data is in foreign language. All encoding (Database, tables, fields) is set to utf8.
If I send something like "якийсь текст" to database via PHP, in database it will look like "ÑÐºÐ¸Ð¹ÑÑŒ Ñ‚ÐµÐºÑÑ‚" and if I retrieve this text from database with PHP I get "якийсь текст" which is fine.
    But when I sent same text to db with node, in db it will be saved as it is(якийсь текст) but when retrieving it from the db with PHP - I am getting just question marks.
In node mysql.createConnection I have set charset: 'utf8'  and added conc.query("SET NAMES utf8") .
So I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
Thanks

Comment: Where are you seeing the question marks? In the client? If so try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17872789/node-js-express-how-do-i-set-response-character-encoding

Answer (score -1):

That's Mojibake. See [*this*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) for causes.

That also discusses "question marks".

Since you have two symptoms, I suggest you have at least two coding errors.  So, see "Best Practice" in that link, too.

Show us:

- The connection string
- `SHOW CREATE TABLE`
- `SELECT HEX(col), col FROM tbl WHERE ...`

It could be "double encoding" -- which is insidious in that it looks ok except when you compare strings.

UTF-8 `як` is hex `D18F D0BA`.  However, if doubly encoded, you get `C391 C28F C390 C2BA`

The `SET NAMES utf8` should have helped; but that is only one of about 5 things that need to match.

node.js needs something like

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({ ... , charset : 'utf8'});
```

(or utf8mb4)