# Decoding garbled JSON from axios.get

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

Brand new to express and relatively inexperienced with JS/TS. Playing around with setting up an express server with two endpoints.The response from httpbin (https://httpbin.org/get -> http://localhost:3031/simpleget) appears fine.

However, I cannot seem to ungarble JSON that comes from http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1 ( http://localhost:3031/users/1 ) .
The response looks something like:

> "��\u000f\u0000 ���w����?JO�_��9��\u0013U>H�z\u000b�]{�\u0014�)�o6Ī\u0004��pc]+ܜ��ǅ\u0006�g�Gg\u000f [�\u001aэ\u0007����\u001a�)<\f�\u0017�{���DK��ʌ�ҳ�h\rz�hS�'�����Nu\u0007��5�v\u0001r��̴\u0006},\u001d;|ںY�\u0003�\u0016;�dw��#�r�dk�#�A/{\u00196��K�$;�i;V��U�Z�&)�4m-#=\u0001�q$&)�$�V\f\u0002����5���(]�\u0004��\u0003��wS3\u000e$��\u0014Eh�$7e�D8dy��:�΅�i\rjlWI�Z���\u0015���O<\u001c�\u00007g�c��"��AǁU!\r���F�q~-�lM�GQ��\u0001k�Dw�\u0018dQ�� N�Sr�:�sP��̶\u0017���\u001e9�w\u0005"

Tried textdecoder, json stringify, unicode conversion and many other approaches but nothing seems

```
const express = require("express")
const axios = require("axios")
const cors = require("cors")

const app = express()
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended:true}))
app.use(cors())

app.get("/users/:id", async(req, res) => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(
        `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${req.params.id}`
        )
    res.json(data)
})

app.get("/simpleget", async(req, res) => {
    const {data} = await axios.get("https://httpbin.org/get")
    res.json(data)
})

app.listen(3031)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you looked at the headers in the response, for something like accept-encoding?

Comment: @JonSkeet I see `vary: 'Origin, Accept-Encoding',
  'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
  'cache-control': 'max-age=43200',` in the response header. How do I deal with it?

Comment: This is definitely an encoding issue. Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21284905/4088472

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `Accept-Encoding` with 'application/json' in axios.get header.

The default of it is `gzip`

This is demo code.

```
const express = require("express")
const axios = require("axios")
const cors = require("cors")

const app = express()
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(cors())

app.get("/users/:id", async (req, res) => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(
        `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${req.params.id}`,
        {
            headers: {
                'Accept-Encoding': 'application/json',
            }
        }
    )
    res.json(data)
})

app.get("/simpleget", async (req, res) => {
    const { data } = await axios.get("https://httpbin.org/get")
    res.json(data)
})

app.listen(3031)
```

Install

```
npm install express axios cors
```

Run it

```
node users.js
```

Result if browser open server

```
http://localhost:3031/users/1
```

[image]