# How to set charset using fetch?

Tags: nuxt.js, fetch-api, multipartform-data, nuxtjs3

```
            var body = new FormData()
            
            body.append('deal', this.deal)
            body.append('checksum', await this.checksum(file))
            body.append('file', file)
            const { data } = await useFetch(`/api/${this.deal}/upload`, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'X-Token': useToken() },
                body
            })
```

If i had some non ascii in file name - server decodes it as ISO-8859-1.

Browser sends

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary4Rr7cdF3ADa3y8y8
```

```
    ------WebKitFormBoundary4Rr7cdF3ADa3y8y8
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="deal"
    
    9c500b3f-4bfc-403e-9360-6876eee044d9
    ------WebKitFormBoundary4Rr7cdF3ADa3y8y8
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="checksum"
    
    219998802D0DF28DEFA2E6D7F8839F8DAC958CD2ADE85C93AD0A276EAFA97D85
    ------WebKitFormBoundary4Rr7cdF3ADa3y8y8
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="2 - копия.docx.sig"
    Content-Type: application/pgp-signature
    
    
    ------WebKitFormBoundary4Rr7cdF3ADa3y8y8--
```

How to set charset?

Comment: Read this: "HTTP 1.1 says that the default charset is ISO-8859-1 But ....." (https://www.w3.org/International/articles/http-charset/index#charset)

Comment: I think I can fix it on server, but chrome browser sends filename in utf and not set charset

Comment: Chrome (browser) should to what the (web-)app is asking it to do, and should not do anything on it's own..

Comment: but it sends filename as utf8 and not tell server that

Comment: You should then read it as utf8, when yor server sends us as such

Comment: RFC tells server to read it as  ISO-8859-1

Comment: I do not know anything about your server (and/or it's config), and I would read it in a charset which makes the data correct (despite anything that an RFC has to sa about what should be done)

Comment: It was `nodejs`/`nuxt3`/`mutler` stack.

Comment: Please specify the Content-Type. and charset which will be used in your server config, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17872789/node-js-express-how-do-i-set-response-character-encoding#comment46643919_17877151